# How to print react-code inside code-tag?

Tags: reactjs

I want to show my react code on a webpage, so visitors can read it. How can I convert my react code into a string and print it with indents?

react

```
   const reactcode= (
     <div>
       <div>
        <div>hello world</div>
       </div>
    </div>);
```

Comment: You could do the other way around and use the [html-to-react module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: Separate newline-delineated strings:

```
const reactcode = '<div>' +
'\n  <div>' + 
'\n    <div>hello world</div>' + 
'\n  </div>' + 
'\n</div>)';
```

Method 2: ES2015 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and much simpler

```
const reactcode = `
<div>
   <div>
     <div>hello world</div>
   </div>
</div>`;
```

Note the backticks (`` ` ``) at the start and end of the string.

The reason method 2 works is because template literals can span multiple lines.

**EDIT:**

I just realised that what you're looking for is a way to convert actual React code to a string, not just print a string. It looks like the npm [jsx-to-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-to-string) module could help with this.

Comment: Wow Aron, that is cool! Is there also the chance to use the of the const for both, the printed string and as actual react code?

Comment: Does that help you?

Comment: Aron, thank you so much, that helped me very much, you are my hero!